# How to display images in React Native which are stored using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I want to display the image in my react native which is taken from API

Comment: share what you did so far? code snippet ? follow stackoverflow question guidelines. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. edit your question asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least to ways of achieving this. Both of them are based on `<Image />` component from React Native.

1. First approach is to get image URL from the API and just use is as a source.
2. And the second one is to encode an image to a base64 string on the API side and send it to the react native application.

Here's some basic example of a single React Native component which does the fetch of the URL or Base64 image and shows it:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  someImage: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
  },
});

const DisplayAnImage = () => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://your.api.address/which/returns/images')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
      setImage(json.someUrlOrBase64);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <Image
        style={styles.someImage}
        source={{
          uri: image,
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export default DisplayAnImage;
```

The image size should be set, otherwise it won't be visible.

More details could be found in the official documentation: https://reactnative.dev/docs/image

Comment: thanks, i9or for the quick response, I bring you good tidings
  It worked for me. 

hhh but I am wondering if the same method works in video and record audio? 
and thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no video component available in a standard react native library. You'll have to look for an external library or write it yourself.

Comment: Thanks again i9or for the quick response, and i hope you have a great day.